# Page viewer with preview of previous and next page

Tags: android, android-layout

in my android application I'd like to implement the code to show a preview of the next and the previous activity like a circle image gallery.

I try to explain in more details how this should work. I see in the center of the screen  the actually active activity, in the left of the screen the previous one and in the right of the screen the next one. So in the screen we should will seeing something like the following picture.

[image]

Will anyone know if it is possible to realize this behaviour?

thanks in advance
Simo.

Answer (score 0):

only similar libraries i've found are those:

http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/android-coverflow/

https://github.com/fry15/uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools (third demo called "smaller pages" ) .

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now I will try to use this library and then I will reports feedback about it. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: well you can use opengl , but that's a lot of work and i'm not sure how much effort you want to put for it .

Comment: I finally decided to use this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1). I would like to implement, however, the carousel effect  with in perspective, the previous page and the next.
I implemented the method **@Override public float getPageWidth (int position) {return (0.30f);}** having three pages displayed on the same screen but I don't know how to realize this effect